# Keyboard shortcut to launch applications from the GNOME3 Favourites

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome3

I have just switched from Unity to GNOME 3. The main feature I'm missing is being able to launch the *x*<sup>th</sup> application on my Unity Panel with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>*X*</kbd>.

Is there a similar set of shortcuts, or a way to enable them, in GNOME?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by posting on the Ubuntu GNOME G+ Community.

There's an extension [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/413/dash-hotkeys/).